# Ignore creating beginnings of words in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse all the links in a message.

My Java-Code looks the following:

```java
Pattern URLPATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    "([--:\\w?@%&+~#=]*\\.[a-z]{2,4}/{0,2})((?:[?&](?:\\w+)=(?:\\w+))+|[--:\\w?@%&+~#=]+)?",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher = Patterns.URLPATTERN.matcher(message);
ArrayList<int[]> links = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find())
    links.add(new int[] {matcher.start(1), matcher.end()});
[...]
```

The problem now is that the links sometimes start with a colour-code that looks the following: `[&§]{1}[a-z0-9]{1}`

An example could be: `Please use Google: §ehttps://google.com, and don't ask me.`

With the regex expression, I found somewhere on the internet it will match the following: `ehttps://google.com` but it should only match `https://google.com`

Now how can I change the regular expression above to exclude the following pattern but still match the link that follows just after the color-code?

```regex
[&§]{1}[a-z0-9]{1}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: @markspace Of course it does not, it is not a URL validation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `(?:[&§][a-z0-9])?` pattern (matching an optional sequence of a `&` or `§` and then an ASCII letter or digit) at the beginning of your regex:

```java
Pattern URLPATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:[&§][a-z0-9])?([--:\\w?@%&+~#=]*\\.[a-z]{2,4}/{0,2})((?:[?&]\\w+=\\w+)+|[--:\\w?@%&+~#=]+)?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4Yh7S/1).

When the regex finds `§ehttps://google.com`, the `§e` is matched with the optional non-capturing group `(?:[&§][a-z0-9])?`, that is why it is "excluded" from the Group 1 value.

There is no need using `Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL` with your regex, there is no `.` and no `^`/`$` in the pattern.